# exclude id from selection mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to exclude an id from table but seem to no get this working.

This is a CodeIgniter datatables that is getting data from 2 tables.

I want to exclude data from warehouse_id 2

```
    function getdata()
    {
            $this->load->library('datatables');
            $this->datatables->select("products.id as productid, image, code, name, size, color, type, gender, price, (CASE WHEN sum(warehouses_products.quantity) Is Null THEN 0 ELSE sum(warehouses_products.quantity) END) as totalQuantity");
            $this->datatables->from('products');
            $this->datatables->join('warehouses_products', 'products.id=warehouses_products.product_id', 'left');
            $this->datatables->where('warehouses_products.warehouse_id !=', '2');
            $this->datatables->group_by("productid");

      echo $this->datatables->generate();
      }
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /system/database/DB_active_rec.php on line 990
```

Comment: [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) `$this->db->where('name !=', $name);`

Answer (score 0):

Where should come after join.
Link for [mysql select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
Also, i dont know "datatables" implementation but i think there is single quote missing at where method.

I've look into "codeigniter" examples, and by there example it should be:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name); 
$this->db->where('email', $email); 

Custom key or value method 

$this->db->where('name !=', $name); 
// Produces WHERE 'name' != '$name'
```

Therefor your where method should be

```
$this->datatables->where('warehouses_products.warehouse_id !=', '2');
```

Comment: I add the quotes, but maybe is not correct write the quotes... thanks

Comment: @Dario, Is there a chance of seeing the current code you're using ?

Comment: Sure, just tell me what part of code do you want to see, because i write here the controller, maybe will help the datatables library to see what references are using to exclude some data from table.

Comment: @Dario, The code you pasted at this current question but after all the changes we told you. (just edit your post)

Comment: @Dario, I already told you to put the Where method after JOIN and i also gave you a Select MySQL link so you could see the correct order of SQL select.

Comment: I figure out the error on this: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in system/database/DB_active_rec.php on line 990

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got your quotes and etc right... the where bit looks wrong use "" for the full where sql and for field values use single quotes... also since the id is an integer dont really need quotes around it.

Since you are grouping by the product id even if the product is in warehouse id 2 it will not be excluded if that product exists in any other warehouse

so if you want to exclude all the products that are in warehouse id 2 you should use a subselect in where  clause something along the lines of where "product_id not in (Select * from products where warehouse=id = 2)"

alot depends what you are really trying to achieve